# How can I edit my python code to prevent .xlsx file form saying "We found a problem with some content in file.xlsx" when opened?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel-formula, openpyxl

When I open my .xlsx file, I am greeted with "We found a problem with some content in file.xlsx...". Once it fixes, it says "Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part."

It is removing my vlookups I am adding via Python with the below code:

```py
wb = load_workbook(f'{working_folder}\\{final_excel_file_name}')
sheet1_name = '-'.join(re.findall(r'[0-9]+', str(wb.worksheets[0])))
sheet2_name = '-'.join(re.findall(r'[0-9]+', str(wb.worksheets[1])))

sheet1 = wb[sheet1_name]
sheet2 = wb[sheet2_name]

sheet1['Q1'] = ''
for cell in sheet1['Q']:
    cell.value = "=VLOOKUP(I{0},'" + sheet2_name + "'!I:I,1,FALSE)"

wb.save(f'{working_folder}\\test.xlsx')
```

**Is there a way to format my cell.value to prevent excel from wanting to delete it when opening?**
**Additionally, if you have any suggestions on how to improve my code, it would be apricated.**

I'm expecting to have =VLOOKUP(I2,Sheet2!I:I,1,FALSE) in every cell in column "Q". I2 Dynamically changing as it goes down (I3, I4, etc).

Comment: The formulae are always going to contain `{0}` because the string is neither an f-string nor have you called the `format()` method. You can easily check this. Presumably, you want something like this `formula = f"VLOOKUP{cell.row},'{ws.title}'!,I:I,FALSE)"`

Comment: Exactly @CharlieClark. moken's post below got me to that knowledge and it is all working perfect now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the `sheet1_name` and `sheet2_name` `join` section is supposed to do.
From the example formula provided

```
=VLOOKUP(I2,Sheet2!I:I,1,FALSE)
```

it appears that one sheet name is `Sheet2` and you are adding the formula to `Sheet1`. However those lines of code would just return hyphenated numbers???
If you can better explain this section, can perhaps comment on it further.

Anyway for the purposes of answering the question I'll assume the sheet names are;
`Sheet1` where the formulas will be written
`Sheet2` where the table exists

That part of the formula you can use the cell for a row count and using an `f string` is easier to understand how your formula should be put together;

```
...
sheet2_name = 'Sheet2'
### Loop each cell in column Q to max used row
for cell in sheet1['Q']:   
    ### Use an f string to create the formula
    cell.value = f"=VLOOKUP(I{cell.row},'{sheet2_name}'!A:A,1,FALSE)"
```

Note the single quotes around the sheet name `'{sheet2_name}'` would only be necessary if the sheet name did actually have spaces.

Comment: It's simpler always to quote the sheet name. This avoid having to change the code when you need to.

Comment: This is a report that is going to run monthly and the sheet names will change, but will always be a date. The `sheet#_name` variables are getting the name of the worksheet so I can work with it. It's extracting the numbers and inserting an - in between the two sets. This worked for the most part. I just needed to still use my entire function with the `f string`! Thank you!